# ros urdf tutorial on osx

Tags: ros, urdf, roslaunch, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did some of the turtle sim tutorials and now I'm trying to do an urdf tutorial but I'm running into some issues. What's going on here?

```
$ roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:='$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'
... logging to /Users/Jackson/.ros/log/0b166d51-d251-11e5-96bf-a0999b17aec5/roslaunch-lapfeet.local-1073.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

started roslaunch server http://lapfeet.local:51266/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.16
 * /use_gui: False

NODES
  /
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[joint_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [1078]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_state_publisher/state_publisher]: can't locate node [state_publisher] in package [robot_state_publisher]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rviz/rviz]: can't locate node [rviz] in package [rviz]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 5, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
[joint_state_publisher-1] process has died [pid 1078, exit code 1, cmd /Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/Users/Jackson/.ros/log/0b166d51-d251-11e5-96bf-a0999b17aec5/joint_state_publisher-1.log].
log file: /Users/Jackson/.ros/log/0b166d51-d251-11e5-96bf-a0999b17aec5/joint_state_publisher-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226541/ros-urdf-tutorial-on-osx/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_state_publisher/state_publisher]: can't locate node [state_publisher] in package [robot_state_publisher]
> ```

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rviz/rviz]: can't locate node [rviz] in package [rviz]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jackson/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 5, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

Just making sure: have you `source`d the correct `setup.bash` / workspace? These error messages point to some issues with the environment you are trying to start the launch file in (not being able to find `rviz` fi).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0